# Django CMS : How to get placeholder html content?

Tags: django-cms

Model:
    from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField

```
MyModel(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    placeholder = PlaceholderField('my_model')
```

I want to retrieve the placeholder html content in a variable, something like that :

```
MyModel.objects.get(id=1).placeholder.get_html_content()
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Do you need the variable in your template? If so, there is a [template tag in `django-cms` 3 called `render_placeholder`](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html#render-placeholder) that allows you to easily assign the content of the placeholder to a variable: `{% render_placeholder mymodel_instance.my_placeholder as placeholder_content %}`

Comment: No, i need it at "python" side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work!

Given that you have access to `request` object:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

from cms.plugin_rendering import render_placeholder


obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
html = render_placeholder(obj.placeholder, RequestContext(request))
```

If you don't have access to `request` object, you can use the `RequestFactory`to mock `request` object

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.test.client import RequestFactory


def get_request(language=None):
    request_factory = RequestFactory()
    request = request_factory.get('/')
    request.session = {}
    request.LANGUAGE_CODE = language or settings.LANGUAGE_CODE

    # Needed for plugin rendering.
    request.current_page = None
    request.user = AnonymousUser()
    return request
```

Comment: Works great. Just missing this import : from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

Comment: I comment this answer because people may find it on google, here's a newer answer : http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/upgrade/3.4.html#manual-plugin-rendering